# What is the difference between client & company in SAP enterprise structure

Tags: sap-erp

In enterprise structure client is termed as highest organizational unit. It is synonym to corporate group. So how it is different from Company (Not Company Code). Where we configured it in the enterprise structure.

Answer (score 0):

The client is more a technical separation than an organizational. Clients work independent from another, sharing only the application code and a few more technical customizing settings (mostly because they represent DDIC objects, as DDIC objects themselves are also client independent). The client is often used by SAP hosting service suppliers to let completely independent companies work within the same SAP system.